Progress bar for Telegram messages
aiogram 2.25
When user clicks on ReplyButton in my TG bot, he waits while some function will be done, how i can show to user progress bar or waiting message?
@dp.message_handler(commands=['fill_table'])
async def fill_table(message: types.Message):
    check_errors(168)
    await message.answer('table filled', reply_markup=index_keyboard)

while function check_errors(168) execute, user should be notified
